# Copy column of list to new column of same list in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I want to copy the whole column values to a new column.
As a solution, I prepare a workflow:

`SET FIELD TO VALUE and make the workflow start when item update`

But, I have 16000+ rows and to manually update each one is not possible as of now.
I also tried using Microsoft Flow but no success.

Could anyone please suggest a way to achieve it.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I updated using QUICK EDIT under VIEW. Changed the view to 2000 rows at a time and updated all the rows in 8 times. Took around 15 min, but for one time update, it is ok. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest PowerShell for such 'migration' work. Script from [here](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/01/copy-list-column-values-from-one-to-another.html),the script need to be run in SharePoint server.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Parameters
$SiteURL = "http://siteurl/"
$listName = "list"

$web = Get-SPweb $SiteURL

#Use the Display Names
$CopyFromColumnName = "Description" #column copy source
$CopyToColumnName = "Desc"  #destination column

#Get the List
$list = $web.lists[$ListName]

#Get all Items 
$Items = $list.Items

ForEach ($Item in $items)
{
   #copy data from one column to another
   $item[$copyToColumnName] = $item[$copyFromColumnName]

   #Do a system update to avoid Version and to Keep same metadata
   $item.SystemUpdate($false)
}
```

For SharePoint online, refer [this thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/265359/powershell-script-to-copy-list-items-from-one-column-to-another-in-a-sharepoint), replace the iterate logic as pageing.

```
$Query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
    $Query.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='TRUE'/></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit Paged='TRUE'>$BatchSize</RowLimit></View>"

    $Counter = 0
    #Batch process list items - to mitigate list threshold issue on larger lists
    Do { 
        #Get items from the list
        $ListItems = $List.GetItems($Query)
        $Ctx.Load($ListItems)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        $Query.ListItemCollectionPosition = $ListItems.ListItemCollectionPosition

        #Loop through each List item
        ForEach($ListItem in $ListItems)
        {
            //to do copy field value
            $Counter++
            Write-Progress -PercentComplete ($Counter / ($List.ItemCount) * 100) -Activity "Processing Items $Counter of $($List.ItemCount)" -Status "Searching Unique Permissions in List Items of '$($List.Title)'"
        }
    } While ($Query.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I updated using QUICK EDIT under VIEW. Changed the view to 2000 rows at a time and updated all the rows in 8 times. Took around 15 min, but for one time update, it is ok. :)